# How to define a generic type for real numbers for Python type hinting

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to define a custom type that accepts all real numbers (for Python type hinting). Actually, I would like to support any number type that allow meaningful comparison, but sticking to just the real numbers is good enough. However the way I am doing it does not seem to be correct. For instance with the following snippet:

```
import numbers
import typing

MyDataType = typing.NewType('MyDataType', numbers.Real)

def f(a : MyDataType) -> None:
    pass

f(5)
```

I get mypy complaining that

> Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "int"; expected "MyDataType"

How do I actually achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Why not use numbers.Real directly?

Comment: @funnydman The idea was to give a meaningful name to the data type, much like a typedef - the snippet above is just for illustration. Anyway, using numbers.Real directly doesn't work either, I get the same mypy error.